# SQL Query Needed for Joomla 1.5

Tags: sql, joomla

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I have a Joomla 1.5 installation and I'm updating to 3.1.5 but the problem is the current site used a plugin which uses the Key Reference of each article to generate the Meta Page Title and I need to take this info from each article (220+) and put it under params in the menu item so I currently have the following;

Article

```
TABLE joscontent COLUMN id VALUE 39

TABLE joscontent COLUMN attribs VALUE:

show_title=
link_titles=
show_intro=
show_section=
link_section=
show_category=
link_category=
show_vote=
show_author=
show_create_date=
show_modify_date=
show_pdf_icon=
show_print_icon=
show_email_icon=
language=
keyref=Page Title Value is Currently Here
readmore=
```

MENU ITEM

```
table      column   value
jos_menu   link     index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=39
jos_menu   params   

show_noauth=
show_title=
link_titles=
show_intro=
show_section=
link_section=
show_category=
link_category=
show_author=
show_create_date=
show_modify_date=
show_item_navigation=
show_readmore=
show_vote=
show_icons=
show_pdf_icon=
show_print_icon=
show_email_icon=
show_hits=
feed_summary=
page_title=
show_page_title=1
pageclass_sfx=
menu_image=-1
secure=0
```

So is there a way i can submit an SQL query that will take the keyref value from the attribs column and insert the page_title value of the params colum where the Article ID matches the id used in the menu link and this will do every article on the site.

Hope this makes sense!

EDIT THIS SOLUTION WORKED

```
update jos_menu jm
set params = (select concat('show_noauth=
show_title=
link_titles=
show_intro=
show_section=
link_section=
show_category=
link_category=
show_author=
show_create_date=
show_modify_date=
show_item_navigation=
show_readmore=
show_vote=
show_icons=
show_pdf_icon=
show_print_icon=
show_email_icon=
show_hits=
feed_summary=
page_title=',
replace(substr(attribs, locate('keyref=', attribs)+7), 'readmore=', ''),
' 
show_page_title=1
pageclass_sfx=
menu_image=-1
secure=0 ')
from jos_content jc
where jm.link = concat('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=', jc.id))
where Instr(jm.link, 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find a single SQL statement that can do this by using some tricky regular expressions. But I would really suggest that you write a script in PHP which loops through all records and does this job. this will give you more control and the ability to make some error checks.

Comment: Thank you I was in a rush today so I hired a guy on elance to do it and he came up with this which seems to have worked perfectly - another vendor suggested php but I didn't have the time;

Comment: update jos_menu jm
 set params = (select concat('show_noauth=
 show_title=
 link_titles=
 show_intro=
 show_section=
 link_section=
 show_category=
 link_category=
 show_author=
 show_create_date=
 show_modify_date=
 show_item_navigation=
 show_readmore=
 show_vote=
 show_icons=
 show_pdf_icon=
 show_print_icon=
 show_email_icon=
 show_hits=
 feed_summary=
 page_title=',
 replace(substr(attribs, locate('keyref=', attribs)+7), 'readmore=', ''),
 ' 
show_page_title=1
 pageclass_sfx=
 menu_image=-1
 secure=0 ')

Comment: from jos_content jc
 where jm.link = concat('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=', jc.id))
 where Instr(jm.link, 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=')